# Is it possible to coerce slices/vectors into 'Cow<[type]>' in function arguments?

Tags: rust, copy-on-write

When moving an API to use `Cow<[sometype]>`, having to replace:

```
some_func(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

With:

```
some_func(Cow::from(&arg1[..]), Cow::from(&arg2[..]), Cow::from(&arg3[..]));
```

Is fairly dense syntax.

Is there a way that vectors or slices can be coerced into their `Cow` equivalents when passed as function arguments?

---

There might be good reason **not** to do this, for example if you used the same argument to a function many times, the explicit syntax is a hint the `Cow<[]>` version should be assigned a variable and kept. However, I'm interested to know if this is possible.

Comment: I think you might be interested in the `Into` trait. You can then constraint generic types in your function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) trait is what you want.  Declare the function to take `Into<Cow<'a, [T]>>` and call the `into()` method in the function:

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn foo<'a, T: Into<Cow<'a, [u8]>>>(v: T) {
    let x = v.into();
    println!("{:?}", x);
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![0,1,2];
    let s = &[3,4,5];
    foo(v);
    foo(&s[..]);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=325cf69d37a76c65b368f024dd1fe797&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: Note: This is one place where the shadowing is really interesting, if you rename the argument `x` then after shadowing it you can't accidentally reference it any longer.